# How can I display two JPanels with images on a JFrame, and both of the img to be visible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to set as background an aquarium (which is a class that extends `JPanel` and contain the aquarium img), and on top a fish (which is also a class that extends a `JPanel` and contain the fish img).

The problem is that it shows only one image instead of fish in top of the aquarium (either aquarium, or fish depending on which one is added first to the `JFrame`).

**Main**

```
public class Core {
    JFrame window;
    JLabel label;
    ImageIcon img;      
    Aquarium aquarium = new Aquarium();
    JavaFish javaFish = new JavaFish();

    public void start() {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Java Game");
        aquarium.add(javaFish);
        window.add(aquarium);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Core c = new Core();
        c.start();
    }
}
```

**Aquarium**

```
public class Aquarium extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;
    //Initiate aquarium width 
    public int width;
    //Initiate aquarium height
    public int height;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/AquariumBackground.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Image not fount!");
        }

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, this);
    }               
}
```

**Fish**

```
public class JavaFish extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage img;
    int xPos = 50;
    int yPos = 50;

    public JavaFish() {
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage JavaFish = LoadImage("img/JavaFish.png");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(JavaFish, xPos, yPos, 100, 100, null);
        repaint();
    }

    BufferedImage LoadImage(String FileName) {
        img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File (FileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java Swing doesn't allow components like `JPanel` to be superimposed on one another (to my knowledge). The way I would do it would be to have a single `JPanel` that you first draw the aquarium on, then draw the fish on top of that in the same `JPanel`.

Comment: @Alerra, a JPanel is just like any other component. It can be added to a Jpanel and the layout manager will determine its size and location. If you have a transparent image, then you will need to make the panel non-opaque so the background can show through. But your suggestion to paint both images in the same panel is a good one.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for correcting my imprecision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that it shows only one image instead of fish in top of the aquarium (either aquarium, or fish depending on which one is added first to the JFrame).

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` which respects the preferred size of any component added to it.

By default a `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` and if you don't specify a constraint the component gets added to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`, which means the component is automatically resized to fill the space of the frame.

So the component you add to the frame will be sized to fill the frame. The component you add to the panel will have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

So some custom painting tips:

1. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel to return the size of the image so the layout manager can do its job
2. Invoke super.paintComponent(..) as the first statement to make sure the background gets cleared.
3. Don't read the image in the paintComponent() method. This method can be called whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted, so it not efficient to keep reading the image. Instead the image should be read in the constructor of the class.
4. Don't invoke repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite painting loop.

Also, components should be added to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible.

Having said all of the above, Alerra's suggestion in the comment to paint both images in the same panel is a good idea. It simplifies the painting and you can even paint multiple fish easily by keeping an ArrayList of imgages that you want to paint. Then you would just paint the background and then iterates through the ArrayList to paint the individual fish.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example. The example only draws Rectangle, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks @Alerra ! I took your advise.  I have used only one  panel to draw all my images, and it works.